# Making a (worldly) task obstacle for salat

Tags: salat, muslim-practices

I understand that salat is an important or perhaps the most important pillar of Islam. Whenever we have to choose between performing salat and an worldly task, definitely we must choose salat.

I heard one of my friends saying that, there is no rahmat from Allah Subhanatawala for a task which becomes an obstacle for (hinders) salat. Today, when I was saying this to somebody, he asked (in good intention) whether this is a hadith.

I have searched but failed to find a reference for the above. Do you think you can find any sort of reference for this?

Comment: please note prayer is not one of 5 pillars in Shia Islam. but is one of practices of Islam. 5 pillars are different in shia and sunni Islam.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala Yes, my question is from Sunni view.

Comment: so better to mention it clearly in question to receive answers specifically from the view point you need.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala IMHO, the answer will have nothing to do with the view. If there is, the person who answers will want to mention the view from which he is answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is found in [this question and answer](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/28582),

> The saying, “Allah will not put blessing in an action which distracts
>   [a person] from Salāh,” is not a hadīth, but a common saying amongst
>   people.
>
> The meaning however is correct, as any action which becomes a means of
>   sin is itself a sin, and Allāh Ta‘ālā does not put barakah in sin.